# fread stalls on socket but fget doesnt?

Tags: c, sockets, proxy

I'm working on a proxy server in c. I've gotten rather far using a combination of fread and fgets in different places but would like to reconcile and understand the difference. In the following example, I'm trying to use fread in a place i previously used fget successfully. Instead my server now hangs at the fread line. What's the difference and why is my program hanging?

```
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket)
{
    FILE *request = fdopen(clntSocket, "r");
    char reader[2000];
    size_t q; //typo before
    while((q=fread(reader, 1, sizeof(reader), request))>0) {  //hangs here!
        printf("i read something!\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

thanks!!

EDIT:  so if i make the line "while((q=fread(reader, 1, 1, request))>0) {"

i get "i read something" all over my screen...

not sure what this means. So is it correct that fread will literally do nothing if there isn't at least your buffer's size number of characters present in the stream?

Comment: size_t q;  sorry.. type translating to stack

Answer (score 4):

`fgets` returns when a newline is read while `fread` will block until requested number of bytes are available in the stream or on EOF. In your case, the call blocks because you do not have 2000 bytes of data ready in the stream.

Comment: THIS MUST BE IT. you sir are a champion. will check right away

Comment: keep in mind fread will return as soon as EOF is reached (end of file)

Comment: what's the preferred way to get around this problem... should i use a 1 byte buffer?

Comment: I get that EOF will cause a return... but my http request won't contain that right?

Comment: @MattDean: It depends on what you want to do. If you want to read a character at a time, just use `getc` instead of fread.

Comment: so the basic goal (for our purposes here) is to blindly read in an http request. I can use fget (and have used it) to read the first line which contains host information etc... everything else could be binary data as far as i'm concerned (like in a post) so it's worth freading...

Answer (score 0):

Using `fread()` instead of `recv()` to read on a TCP socket seems strange to me..?

Anyway, `fread` is blocking as long as there is nothing to read. You should always check that a socket is ready to perform reading or writing, using `select()` for example on linux.

Comment: Why does that seem weird to you? The purpose of `stdio` is to buffer data for piecemeal reading, so if that's what you want, why not use it?

Comment: agreed, it's nice to wrap sockets as files so you can use boss functions like fread.. except when you can't like apparently i can't haha