# Using fread() hangs until killed

Tags: c

This is the general structure of my code:

```
if (contentLength > 0)
{
    // Send POST data
    size_t sizeRead = 0;
    char buffer[1024];
    while ((sizeRead < contentLength) && (!feof(stream)))
    {
        size_t diff = contentLength - sizeRead;
        if (diff > 1024)
            diff = 1024;

        // Debuging
        fprintf(stderr, "sizeRead: %zu\n", sizeRead);
        fprintf(stderr, "contentLength: %ul\n", contentLength);
        fprintf(stderr, "diff: %zu\n", diff);

        size_t read = fread(buffer, 1, diff, stream);
        sizeRead += read;

        exit(1);

        // Write to pipe
        fwrite(buffer, 1, read, cgiPipePost);

        exit(1);
    }
}
```

However, the program hangs when it hits the fread() line. If I add an exit() before that line, the program exists. If I add it after, the program hangs until I send a SIGINT signal.

Any help would be appreciated, I have been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Thanks

Comment: What type of stream is `stream`? An input stream to a cgi/fastcgi program?

Comment: Its from a socket accepting connections on a certain port. "stream = fdopen(socket, "r+");"

Comment: Not answer to question,but isn't `fwrite(buffer,read,1/*=sizeof(char)*/,cgiPipePost);`? see order of params.

Comment: Also,if `fgets()` read nothing,you try to print it in next `fwrite()` call. Instead of do directly `        sizeRead += read;` after `fread()`,make sure such a function have returned nonzero value.

Comment: can you check once with `fread_unlocked`? If it's hanged inside `fread`, my doubt is probably someone else has set the lock on the stream

Comment: I replaced fread() with fread_unlocked() and it still hangs

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008977/fread-stalls-on-socket-but-fget-doesnt?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

`fread` tries to fill an internal buffer.  Depending on the implementation, you may be able to stop or limit it by setting the buffering mode (in particular, setting `_IONBF`, see `setbuf`, should work for all implementations).  The general rule, though, is to avoid mixing counted I/O on sockets with stdio at all—to use raw `read` calls.

Also, while it's not biting you here, a `!feof(stream)` test is almost always wrong: people mean this to be predictive (EOF is about to occur), but `feof` is only "post-dictive": after a read operation fails (`getc` or `fgetc` returns `EOF`), the `feof` and `ferror` indicators allow you to discover why the previous failure occurred.